# Run 'Serial.begin(9600)' before loop()

Tags: serial, c++, class

My sketch looks somehow like this:

```
ClassA classA;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    classA = ClassA();
    Serial.println("Bar")

    ...
}

void loop() {
    classA.functionFoo();
}
```

The constructor of `ClassA` however calls some internal methods that perform a `Serial.println()`.

My problem is, that the first (implicit) call of the constructor of `ClassA` comes in the first line of the sketch with

```
ClassA classA;
```

This is before the Serial interface has been initialized (with `Serial.begin(9600)`). Therefore the Serial.monitor cannot interpret the first messages coming from the serial interface.

How can I either suppress any Serial.writes before the setup function or otherwise make sure that the Serial interface is initialized before the setup function?

Comment: Make `classA` a pointer and create the new object with `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your current object a pointer so it isn't instantiated:

```
ClassA *classA;
```

Then create an object with new:

```
classA = new ClassA();
```

The constructor is then only called when the object is made.

Note that you will have to change your accessors to `->`:

```
classA->myFunction();
```

Comment: Adding the `classA = new ClassA();` in the `setup()` function just after calling  `Serial.begin(9600);` will be a quite good solution, but as for the use of `bool bSerialReady` solution, the rework will be important (replacing `classA.<function()>` by `classA-><function()>`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be sure that your `classA` object doesn't use the `Serial.println()` function before the baudrate is defined, it is necessary to add functions in your `class ClassA` and to inform from `setup()` your `classA` object.

The simplest way is to add:

1. a boolean `bool bSerialReady`to keep the status of the Serial object,
2. in all `ClassA` constructors, initialize that `bSerialReady = false;`,
3. add a function `void SetSerialReady()` to switch the status `bSerialReady = true;`. The function should be called in the `setup()`function just after `Serial.begin(9600);`,
4. and in all functions of `ClassA`, add a if-condition `if (bSerialReady)` before calling the `Serial.println()`.

Your `class ClassA` will become:

```
class ClassA
{
private:
    bool bSerialReady;
public:
    ClassA() {
        // ...
        // Initialize bSerialReady
        bSerialReady = false;
    };
    void SetSerialReady() {
        bSerialReady = true;
    };
};
```

Your `setup()` function becomes:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    classA.SetSerialReady();
    ...
}
```

And in functions of `ClassA`, it looks like:

```
if (bSerialReady) {
    Serial.println("Bar");
}
```

Comment: Plus, you'll probably want some logic to store and re-issue the messages that would have been issued before bSerialReady became set.

Comment: not a bad solution, however, it is only about debug messages. I wouldn't want to change my code too much for them...

Comment: @speendo, could you provide an example of your `class ClassA` source code using the `Serial.println()` function to display debug message ? Did you have used the same template in the rest of the source code ?